# FBXLoader can't find version number of fbx file

Tags: reactjs, three.js, loader, fbx

I'm trying to load a .fbx file, the loader.load function throws the following error: 
THREE.FBXLoader: Cannot find the version number for the file given.

I don't know how to solve this problem. How can I check in the fbx file if it has a version number?

Below you can find the react component that I've written. When I test the app, I see only a black canvas.

I tried two different files, but have the same error for both files.

```
export default class myComponent extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      45,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      1,
      2000
    );
    camera.position.set(2, 18, 28);

    const scene = new THREE.Scene();

    const light = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0xffffff, 0x444444);
    light.position.set(0, 1, 0);
    scene.add(light);

    const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(28, 28, 0x303030, 0x303030);
    scene.add(gridHelper);

    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    this.model.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    const loader = new FBXLoader();

    let model = new THREE.Object3D();

    loader.load(
      './3DModels/MHT.fbx',
      function(object) {
        model = object.scene;
        scene.add(model);
      },
      undefined,
      function(e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    );

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={ref => (this.model = ref)} />;
  }
}
```

FBXLoader throws this error: THREE.FBXLoader: Cannot find the version number for the file given.

Comment: how do you serve your fbx files? is there a failed request for the mht.fbx in the network tab in the browser?

Comment: Can you please share one of your FBX files in this thread? Besides, do you know which DCC tool has exported the respective FBX files? Maybe Blender?

Comment: @Mugen87 I downloaded the file it from this website [https://www.cgtrader.com/items/632244/download-page] and included it in my project.

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko I checked the Network tab and it's loading the file with status 200 OK . Does it mean my FBXLoader is not working, but it appears it's checking something in the file if it can't find the version number, right?

Comment: I can only debug the loader if you can share the file. Consider to send me a PM with the asset.

Comment: @Mugen87 I don't know how to send PM on StackOverflow, I'm very new. But here is the link to file on MyDrive that I actually would like to show [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zT7XV4S5UmaEvQWCS7ndIyeXI-4NOe5q/view)

Comment: Um, I can load the file with the latest version of `FBXLoader`. I have just replaced the model file in this [example](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_fbx) and commented out the animation related code. The final code looks like so: https://jsfiddle.net/x50ewLa3/

Comment: @Mugen87Ok thank you, how do you know the file is loading though if you can't see it? In your jsfiddle example I can't see a 3d model.  In my example I figured out that the FBXLoader is trying to find a version number in the index.html file, and of course it can't find a version number there. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you hosting your files in your src folder or public folder? 
You should be **keeping the fbx files in public folder**.

The loader scans the document and parses the text to find what it needs to load. Case with working in react is this will trigger before the DOM is rendered, so it basicaly can't the version because it sees no file.

I worked it out while trying to "debug" the loader code. It turned out it was me :)

Another fbx thing is you should always use the latest loader plugin. [Under this link](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/typescript-fbxloader-not-a-constructor-problem/3706/2) you will find both the link to the original plugin and the example how to convert it to React module.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
loader.load('./3DModels/MHT.fbx', function(object) {
  ...
})
```

instead：

```
const path = require(./3DModels/MHT.fbx);//写在类的外面
loader.load(path, function(object) {
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have meeted the same problem just now, you can try to debug like this:

I find the reason that my project use [Mockjs](https://github.com/nuysoft/Mock)  which make `XMLHttpRequest` become `MockXMLHttpRequest`:

```js
// relative code in three.js:
request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
                // if you use Mockjs, this become MockXMLHttpRequest but not XMLHttpRequest 
               // this.response not is ArrayBuffer ,there is the bug.
                var response = this.response;
                var callbacks = loading[ url ];
```

Here just my case which maybe help you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! There is no mention (I did not find it) that the user uses Mockjs. Are you sure you are replying to the question? If it is not the case, as you can not comment, please mention it.

Comment: @David García Bodego There just my case and I think this maybe help someone.

Comment: @David García Bodego At first ,I think bug is in threejs or fbxLoader code. So If I ask question without debug, I think I will no mention Mockjs too.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error coming up on a ThreeJS RPG game hosted on Heroku. I eventually found a simple solution which worked for me and am posting here for any other poor soul who runs into to this issue.

The issue for me was that when I was downloading the FBX file from mixamo I was downloading just the FBX.binary file. **You need to download the fbx file with the version number **. So I just downloaded the FBX animation as FBX 7.4 and it worked. See image.

Hope this helps someone save the stupid number of hours I wasted on this...

[download fbx 7.4 or 6.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIf1o.png)

Answer (score 0):

this error simply means the ***file was not found*** (or rarely it actually was but wasnt able to find the version number). but mostly it means that it wasnt found.

**this is because as a user here anwsered and pointed out it must be in the *public directory* and not in any assets directory or anywhere not inside public**